# Javascript как передвигать элемент канваса по синусоиде ?

Tags: анимация, canvas, javascript

Здравствуйте , меня интересует вопрос как например круг нарисованный в канвасе заставить двигаться по траектории синусоиды.

Заранее благодарен.

Comment: А вы что-то пробовали сделать вообще?

Comment: ну я нарисовал его в канвасе ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Задать базовые координаты x,y кругу.
2. По таймеру смещать **x** по формуле **`x1 = x + dx`**, а **y** по формуле **`y1 = y + sin(x-x1) * sy`** (dx - шаг смещения, sy - коэфициент по высоте, чтобы смещение чувствовалось).

Думаю вы идею поняли, и сумев нарисовать круг вы справитесь и с этой задачей.

Comment: спасибо огромное ! Я правда еще не садился за это дело но смысл мне понятен . еще раз спасибо!!